# How to include a prebuilt static library in Android NDK's Android.mk file correctly?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm stuck getting my libraries included inside the Android NDK build.

The libraries are correctly compiled and work fine when creating a dummy cpp file and building everything with a direct g++ command in the shell.

The current Android.mk file doesn't work and throws an error that the corresponding header files (that are part of the .a files) can't be found.

**How do I include prebuilt static libraries correctly?**

My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)


# V8 Base

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE          := v8_base
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := v8_base_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../lib/libv8_base.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


# V8 Nosnapshot

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE          := v8_nosnapshot
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := v8_nosnapshot_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../lib/libv8_nosnapshot.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


# V8GL Runtime

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := v8gl-runtime
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c ../src/v8gl/v8gl.cpp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -D__ANDROID__
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue v8_base v8_nosnapshot

# LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -D__ANDROID__

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

The compiler output is the following, which makes sense, but only shows me that there is no single .a file included and I don't know why:

```
Compile++ thumb  : v8gl-runtime <= v8gl.cpp
(... g++ call)
In file included from jni/../src/v8gl/v8gl.cpp:6:
jni/../src/v8gl/v8gl.h:5:16: error: v8.h: No such file or directory
```

**SOLUTION with absolute path**

Thanks to the hint of @alex-cohn I found out that the includes were falsely pointed out.
So I decided to use an environment variable that is set before calling ndk-build that contains the absolute path. That fixes the problem with the includes.

So the last Module, where the actual inclusion is done, is now looking like:

```
ADK_PATH=/var/whatever/to/your/project/root_not_jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8gl-runtime
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c ../src/v8gl/v8gl.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(ADK_PATH)/external/v8/include

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -D__ANDROID__
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue v8_base v8_nosnapshot
```

Now it also shows that the libraries are included, because they are compiled afterwards - for whatever reason.

**SOLUTION with relative path**

All include paths are relative to the **project root folder** and not the **jni** folder. That means it will land as a compiler -I flag as something like this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../file_in_project.root

# resulting g++ flag:
-Ijni/../file_in_project.root
```

**So there's a difference between the relative include paths and the LOCAL_SRC_FILES, which are relative to the jni folder!**

Comment: Exactly! Now you got it right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have file `v8.h` in directory `../include` or somewhere else...

You should add line

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
```

Note that unlike `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` where you don't need `$(LOCAL_PATH)`, here you must put the full paths of all directories where the necessary `.h` files are.

Comment: Still the same error, I added the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES to the last module, the v8gl-runtime, where they are required. Strangely the compiler includes the libraries still relative. So there's a final g++ command like that:

    -I jni/../../external/v8/include

So that's somehow strange, because I don't know how to make $(LOCAL_PATH) to get to an absolute path starting at /.

Comment: It's OK that the path is not absolute. Can you publish the relevant lines of the new build log (with V=1)? Also, check that the `jni/../../external/v8/include` directory really contains the `v8gl.h` file. Also, check the `#include` statement in the `jni/../src/v8gl/v8gl.cpp` file: is it simply `#include "v8gl.h"`?

Comment: I just realized what the problem was, the paths are relative to the project root folder, not the jni/Android.mk file. Super-stupid and confusing that src files are relative to the jni folder and includes are relative to the project folder. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, you should be careful with your conclusion. `LOCAL_PATH` is where your **Android.mk** persists; if your project contains more than one module, and some are spread around other directories with their own Android.mk files, you'll see that `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` for each module *are relative* to different roots. On the other hand, `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` is relative to the *current directory* where your **make** (in other words, **ndk-build**) runs. True, usually it's the root directory of your Android project. But NDK supports other build scenarios, too.